# Setting height of table row by percentage does not work on Firefox. Solutions?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want the height of the first row to be 70% of the screen. I set the overflow to auto in the div of the first row so that the scrollbar never appears for the whole web page, only for this div. My solution works on Chrome and IE, but does not work on Firefox: on Firefox the size of the first row goes beyond 70%. Any solutions to this?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hyCh/

```
<body>
    <div style="height: 100%;">

        <table style="height: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 70%;">
                    <div class="mainDiv">
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                        AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />AAA AAA<br />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="footerDiv">
                        Copyright some company...
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html 
{ 
    height:100%; 
    margin: 0px;
}

body 
{ 
    height:100%; 
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.mainDiv
{
    background-color: #00FF00; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.footerDiv
{
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: 
The table needs:

```
<tbody style="height: 100%;">
```